# Graph API to send email request length is 4MB? Can we increase that limit?

Tags: c#-4.0, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-sdks, microsoft-graph-mail

Emails are not triggering when the request length exceeds the 4MB limit. In my case i have attachments of 10 which are in KB. Total size of all attachments comes close to 4.1MB. In this case we cant use Upload session as minimum size of attachment should be 3MB. How do we increase the request size of graph API?
Is there any solution?

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered zipping the attachments into one folder and then creating an upload session? Please give that a try and share your experience

Answer (score 0):

You can use [attachment:CreateUploadsession API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/attachment-createuploadsession?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http) call, using this approach you can attach a file if the file size is between 3 MB and 150 MB. But please be aware that Exchange Online lets [administrators customize the message size limit](https://www.microsoft.com/microsoft-365/blog/2015/04/15/office-365-now-supports-larger-email-messages-up-to-150-mb) for Microsoft 365 mailboxes, including any message attachments. By default, this message size limit is 35 MB.